# Sub keys always lit

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace

By sub keys I mean the two keys next to the home button on my Galaxy Ace. Even when the screen is off they are still lit up. Other than that the screen being off acts as normal.

So my question is: Is there a setting or way to get revert to the normal behaviour for the subkeys backlight? (e.g. off when the screen is off)

Comment: what is the question you are asking here?

Comment: @RyanConrad: How to stop the subkeys lights being on constantly. I know it's not right as that is not how it was a week ago, and I'm guessing it certainly doesn't increase battery life. Sorry, I didn't make it clear in the question, will edit now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, which could be wrong, these buttons light up where there are notifications, do they stay lit when you clear the notifications too and turn off the screen?

Comment: I don't have any notifications... But there are some things running in the background that add items to the notifications menu. Apps like IM+ stay open in the background and leave a status message there... I'll check.